# Battery Not Charging

Tags: charging

It was early January this year when this problem started. Every time I charge my phone and leave it for some time, after I get back, the battery is still not charged even the battery icon shows it's charging. I ran my diagnostic app and found out that every time I connect my charger, it would show that it is "Discharging" even the battery icon shows otherwise. There would be times that it would say "charging" but after sometime it would again go back to "Discharging" status. I had my battery checked and it is in good condition, my charger is also in good condition. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Check the charger with any other phone. If it works fine, problem should be in phone. Verify and contact the dealer.

Comment: How long is "some time", and is your phone doing anything (like checking a really full pop3 mailbox?)

Comment: What phone do you have?